# SQLAlchemy, is there any way to set filter on relationship condition

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have ORM models.

```
class A:
   id = ....
   type = 'dynamic' or None 

class B:
   id =...
   rels = relationship(A)
```

Is there any way to set option on `rels` relationship, which allows me after `session.query(B).get(id).rels` get already filtered data.

Answer (score 0):

This is described in the [Specifying Alternate Join Conditions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions) section in the docs:

```
rels = relationship(A, primaryjoin=and_(B.a_id == A.id, A.type == "dynamic"))
```

The caveat is that this filtering is global and not configurable per-query.